# php form not submitting, page just reloades

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't get my form to submit. I used similar code to submit a different form and it worked fine, I just can't see why it does not work this time.

I don't get any errors. I tried error reporting I couldn't get any errors. The form input is sticky so the page reloads and the input is still there.

This is my html form:

```
    <form action="evenement_maken.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <input type="text" name="ev_naam" class="input-lg form-control" value='<?php echo (isset($_POST['ev_naam']) ? $_POST['ev_naam'] : "" );?>'> 

             <input type="text" name="ev_datum">

                <input type="text" name="ev_adres" class="input-lg form-control" placeholder="Vul hier het adres van het evenement in..." value='<?php echo (isset($_POST['ev_adres']) ? $_POST['ev_adres'] : "" );?>'>

                <textarea class="input-lg form-control" rows="10" name="ev_omschrijving" id="textarea" placeholder="Korte omschrijving van het evenement...">
          <?php  
              if(isset($_POST['ev_omschrijving'])){
              echo htmlentities($_POST['ev_omschrijving'], ENT_QUOTES);
              }
          ?>
        </textarea>
            <button type="submit" class="pull-right btn btn-danger" name="submit">Opslaan</button>   
        </form>
```

And my php code:

```
<?php

 $ev_naam = $ev_datum = $ev_omschrijving = $ev_adres = "";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $ev_naam = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ev_naam']);
    $ev_datum = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ev_datum']);
    $ev_omschrijving = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ev_omschrijving']);
    $ev_adres = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ev_adres']);


    if ($ev_naam=='') {
      echo "<script>alert('Vul alsjeblieft alle velden in!')</script>";
      exit();// zorgt ervoor dat de rest van het script niet wordt uitgevoerd

    } else {

      $insert_evenementen = "INSERT INTO evenementen (ev_naam,ev_datum,ev_omschrijving,ev_adres)
              VALUES ( '$ev_naam','$ev_datum','$ev_omschrijving','$ev_adres')";

        $run_evenementen = mysqli_query($conn, $insert_evenementen);

        if (mysqli_query($conn, $insert_evenementen)) {
          echo "<script>alert('Post is succesvol opgeslagen!')</script>";
          echo "<script>window.open('evenement_maken.php','_self')</script>";
        }
    }

}
?>
```

This is the form that does submit properly (only uploading the img to ftp is not working):

```
    <form action="post_maken.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h4>Titel: </h4>
            <input type="text" name="post_titel" class="input-lg form-control" value='<?php echo (isset($_POST['post_titel']) ? $_POST['post_titel'] : "" );?>' required> 
        <h4>Inhoud: </h4>
            <textarea class="input-lg form-control" rows="10" name="post_inhoud" id="textarea" required>

          if(isset($_POST['post_inhoud'])){
          echo htmlentities($_POST['post_inhoud'], ENT_QUOTES);
          }
      ?>
    </textarea>
        <h4>Categorie:</h4>
            <select class="form-control" name="categorie_id" >
        <option value="null" >selecteer een categorie...</option>
        <?php

                $categorie = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM categorie");

                while ($cat_row=mysqli_fetch_array($categorie, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

                    $cat_naam=$cat_row['cat_naam'];

                  echo "<option value='$cat_naam'>$cat_naam</option>";

                } 
    </select>

        <h4>Afbeelding toevoegen</h4>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                        Zoeken&hellip; 
                    </span>
                </span>

            </div>

      <input type="file" name="post_img"/>


            <p class="help-block">Voeg een afbeelding voor je blogpost toe.</p>
            <br>
        <button type="submit" class="pull-right btn btn-danger" name="submit">Opslaan</button>   
    </form>
```

And the php code:

```
<?php 

$post_titel = $post_datum = $post_inhoud = $categorie_id = "";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$post_titel = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['post_titel']);
$post_datum = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, date('m-d-y'));
$post_inhoud = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['post_inhoud']);
$categorie_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['categorie_id']);
$post_img = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_FILES['post_img']['name']);
$post_img_tmp = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_FILES['post_img']['tmp_name']);

if ($post_titel=='' || $categorie_id=='null' || $post_inhoud=='') {

  echo "<script>alert('Vul alsjeblieft alle velden in!')</script>";
  exit();

} else {

  move_uploaded_file($post_img_tmp, "post_img/$post_img");

  $post_bron = 0;

  $post_datum = date("y-m-d"); 

  $insert_posts = "INSERT INTO post (post_title,post_inhoud,post_datum,categorie_id, post_img, post_bron)
          VALUES ( '$post_titel','$post_inhoud','$post_datum','$categorie_id','$post_img','$post_bron')";

    $run_posts = mysqli_query($conn, $insert_posts);

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $insert_posts)) {
      echo "<script>alert('Post is succesvol opgeslagen!')</script>";
      echo "<script>window.open('post_maken.php','_self')</script>";
    }
}

}
?>
```

I am retrieving values from both databases (connection workes) and displaying it on the website, that also works. I'm using bootstrap 3.

Screenshot of my database table:
[image: database screenshot]

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? I have been staring at this for hours.

Comment: Did you check the content of `$_POST` if anything is posted?

Comment: I checked this: `<?php var_dump($_POST);?>` and got following result: `array(5) { ["ev_naam"]=> string(4) "test" ["ev_datum"]=> string(4) "test" ["ev_adres"]=> string(4) "test" ["ev_omschrijving"]=> string(11) "

test
" ["submit"]=> string(6) "submit" }`

Comment: So the form is submitting alright. U'll need to check the $_FILES to see if your images is uploaded OK. Also be sure the folder `post_img` has sufficient permisons

Comment: The first form does not use post_img folder. Sorry I have been unclear, the question is about the first form, that does not submit (no alert is shown and no values are stored in the database) the second form is just to show that similar form (same db connection) workes fine (exept for the img upload but I think that is a host problem, i checked permissions and the img name is stored in the db but just not oploaded to the server.) Should I use var_dump with $_FILES on the second 'not working' form? Resulted in this `array(0) { }`

Comment: Then you have an error in your SQL. Switch your code up to do this : `if (mysqli_query($conn, $insert_evenementen)) { ... }else{ echo mysqli_erro($con); }`. Your code is open to SQL injection, I suggest you look into prepared statements :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a SQL error. Its always good to check and output mysqli_erros when they occur. Switch your code up to do this

```
if (mysqli_query($conn, $insert_evenementen)) { 
    // query was succesful
}else{ 
    echo mysqli_erro($cnon); // sthing went wrong
}
```

Your code is open to SQL injection, I suggest you look into prepared statements

```
<?php
//procedural example from http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
$city = "Amersfoort";

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $city);

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* bind result variables */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $district);

    /* fetch value */
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

    printf("%s is in district %s\n", $city, $district);

    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```